# Add dynamically javascript to layout in asp.net c# + razor like Page.Title

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm a newbie in ASP.NET and am trying to learn a little more.

I created a layout called Layout.cshtml:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Page.Title</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I set Layout.cshtml as the default layout of all pages in _PageStart.cshtml:

```
@{Layout="~/Shared/Layout.cshtml";};
```

I learned if I change Page.Title in each page, I can dynamically set the page title. For example, I have this in my Default.cshtml and it works fine:

```
@{Page.Title = "HOME";} //the page title has changed to HOME
<h1>This is the home page</h1>
```

My question is, in asp.net+razor does there exist a way to add Javascript (or css) dynamically to  like Page.Title?

Thanks for help dudes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is to use sections.  You place a section with a given name in the layout, then fill in the section's content in each page.

So you could use a "Scripts" section in your layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
    @RenderSection("Scripts")
</head>
```

And then in the individual pages:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src='@Url.Content("scripts/somescript.js")'></script>
}
```

The [ASP.Net MVC blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) has a detailed article about this topic, if you need more info.

Comment: Well, ure the best dbaseman; I'm learning a lot for your good advices. Thanks again dude.